# Strange C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax

This may be a stupid question but I have a code with the following line:

```
Solver *S, *STP = S = 
UseDummySolver ? createDummySolver() : new STPSolver(true);
```

I know the ternary operator but it's the equals signs that confuse me a bit. Can anyone give me some explanation ? Thanks.

Comment: That's a *very ugly* means of assigning two variables at once. *(burn code[rs] like this with fire)*

Comment: There are many reasons for which this code plainly sucks. The double assignment part is just one of them. Not using RAII is another.

Comment: Yes... I didn't even realize that is legal, and I've never seen that before!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Written out, it's

```
Solver *S;
Solver *STP;
S = UseDummySolver ? createDummySolver() : new STPSolver(true);
STP = S;
```

It's very ugly though, I'd not recommend doing that in your code.

The recommended way would be to write it as follows (use initialization, rather than assignment):

```
Solver *S = UseDummySolver ? createDummySolver() : new STPSolver(true);
Solver *STP = S;
```

Comment: Why not use initialization, rather than assignment?

Comment: @Nawaz He is just explaining to the the OP what the code actually _does_.

Comment: @Nawaz: I agree it's better. I just wanted to write it out as clearly as possible for the OP.

Comment: @Nawaz: added a recommendation to use initialization rather than assignment.

Comment: As @Nawaz says, it's not *exactly* the same, since you're assigning `STP` rather than initializing it as in the OP's code.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend this:

```
Solver *S = UseDummySolver ? createDummySolver() : new STPSolver(true);
Solver *STP = S;
```

It is concise, yet neat and clean.

Also, it uses *initialization*, rather than *assignment*. You should prefer initialization over assignment wherever possible.

Comment: Gave you a +1 for the recommendation for initialization vs assignment :)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at chained assignment.

It is the same as:

```
Solver *S;
Solver *STP;
S = UseDummySolver ? createDummySolver() : new STPSolver(true);
STP = S;
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yeah fixed sorry, C++ not my forte.

Comment: Timing is everything :) +1 too

Comment: @sixlettervariables, NominSim, I edited the answer and put in the mistaken dereference.  Sorry about that; the original code confused me.  Not NominSim's fault at all.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator returns a value; based on the `UseDummySolver` Boolean value, it either returns a dummy solver or it returns a new instance of `STPSolver()`.  This returned value is then stored in `STP` and `S`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer either this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Solver> S (  UseDummySolver
                                  ? createDummySolver()
                                  : new STPSolver(true)  );
Solver& STP = *S;
```

or this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Solver> S (  UseDummySolver
                                  ? createDummySolver()
                                  : new STPSolver(true)  );
std::shared_ptr<Solver> STP = S;
```

Both avoid one problem with the code you've got there: we don't need do decide which pointer to call `delete` on when the objects leave scope (or, in fact, remember the need to call `delete` at all). Instead, we just wait until the variables leave scope, then the `Solver` object is automatically removed. `STP` is in the first case umambiguously just another way of accessing the object while it's in scope, in the second case it's an independent "co-owner" of the of the object and both pointers can independently be re-assigned.